# add mvc razor value using javascript while generate control

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to create javascript function that return html checkbox using razor, and has value from parameter that i passing to this function.

```
   function (data) {
//javascript code
         var d = data;
//Razor code start
         return '@Html.CheckBox("Membership[]", false, new { value = d })';
```

thanks.

Comment: You cant. Razor code is parsed on the server before its set to the view. `d` is a javascript variable and does not even exist at that point. But a `CheckBox()` method generates 2 inputs with values `true` and `false` for binding to a `bool` property so changing the `value` attribute would not makes sense anyway

Comment: i need the **value** to store in some control then post it into database.

Comment: Then create the html manually (using `@CheckBox()` makes no sense)

Comment: i only want to save some line so i can save some space in code and make code more readable. btw thanks for your consern.